Are Guidelines for a Regulation legally enforceable, e.g. do they constitute a contract in Australia, against the applicant?
Related to my prior Q. I gather that:

The biscuit-maker petitioner applies to the DVA to use the word Anzac. They complete a form that instructs them to view some Guidelines:


The Department of Veterans’ Affairs (DVA) issues the Use of the Word ‘Anzac’ Guidelines (the Guidelines) to help Australians
comply with the legal restrictions on the use of the word ‘Anzac’. You can view the Guidelines at the following link:


There is not a specific section in the form where they e.g. have to provide any specific recipe or photos of their product etc.

The text of the Regulations itself does not contain any recipe description (or any mention of biscuits), but the Guidelines do. (The actual Regulations are attached as an appendix.)


The Australian press contains stories that one can be fined or imprisoned for not following closely enough the 'traditional' recipe (and shape) for Anzac biscuits. But, how is this legally enforceable against someone who applied and obtained an approval ("proof"), which according to the short text of the Regulations is all they need in court? Does e.g. the instruction to 'view' the Guidelines constitute a legal obligation to follow it thereafter, i.e. is it construed to be a contract? If not, how else is the short/generic "yes" answer (per answer to my previous Q) tied to any obligation to follow the Guidelines, instead of just the Regulations, which (like I said) don't mention any recipe (or even biscuits)?
In fact, it would be even better than a theoretical answer, to provide a concrete court case where:

The applicant had obtained "proof" of approval for 'Anzac biscuits'.

They made biscuits non-conforming to the 'traditional' recipe and sold them as 'Anzac' still.

Their [government-provided] proof was rejected as invalid in court, for the non-conforming biscuits.



Whatever they are, regulations and guidelines associated with them are not a contract. Guidelines are clarifications of regulations which may or may not be legally binding.

@ohwilleke: there's probable complication that in the Australian system, Regulations are seemingly passed by Parliament, so Guidelines might be like actual regulations in other countries, like US or France.  OTOH those Guidelines in question here seem  too informal to be enforceable in court. There are no paras/articles to refer to in them like in US regulations. They gonna be like "you violate page 25, third para from the top in the 2022 edition of the Guidelines?"

"They gonna be like "you violate page 25, third para from the top in the 2022 edition of the Guidelines" I've probably made citations like that in U.S. legal briefs ten or fifteen times in the last year. For example, the IRS webpage and its publications basically has the force of an enacted regulation.

@Lookingforloopholes I'm not sure where you got that idea. Regulations in Australia are created by the executive, not Parliament. Parliament's role is to determine through legislation what powers they delegate to government departments to regulate.

@matty: Things might have changed since 1921. The Regulations in question here have all the appearances of having been passed through parliament, as part of the "WAR PRECAUTIONS ACT REPEAL ACT 1920–1955" https://wipolex-resources-eu-central-1-358922420655.s3.amazonaws.com/edocs/lexdocs/laws/en/au/au057en.pdf

@matty: Therein the Regulations (in question) are described as "Statutory Rules", which (IDK about Australia specifically) in other countries with a similar law system are described as "a type of [subordinate] legislation" https://www.niassembly.gov.uk/assembly-business/covid-19-statutory-rules/faq/

@matty: In Australia, the NSW gov't at least still uses the "subordinate legislation" terminology https://legislation.nsw.gov.au/information/subordinate-legislation#:~:text=Subordinate%20legislation%20is%20law%20made,by%20an%20Act%20of%20Parliament. OTOH, you're probably right that in Australia the situation is more complicated, because the same NSW website continues "On this website, subordinate legislation is simply listed under, or referred as, regulations even though it includes other types of instruments."

@Lookingforloopholes see https://www.legislation.gov.au/F1997B02176/asmade where the enacting language is "I, THE GOVERNOR‑GENERAL in and over the Commonwealth of Australia, acting with the advice of the Federal Executive Council, hereby make the following Regulations under the War Precautions Act Repeal Act 1920, to come into operation forthwith...."  This is the oldest relevant regulation I saw online; it's from 1921.  It's definitely an executive act, not passed by parliament.

@phoog: yeah, it appears though it has then been reaffirmed by Parliament perhaps after the power of the Governor-General to enact Regulations on his own was abrogated. I think technically speaking the GG is not even the executive, but has 'reserve powers' (like the King).

@phoog The are [still] presiding over the Federal Executive Council, so I guess calling them executive isn't too far fetched, even today. https://www.gg.gov.au/about-governor-general/role-governor-general OTOH there's this subtletly (Wikipedia) that "The Governor-General presides over meetings of the Executive Council but is not a member."

@Lookingforloopholes Delegated legislation, or subordinate legislation, means the  same thing as regulations. They aren't really "legislation" in the normally understood sense, despite the confusing name, which means something more like "law made by delegation of the power of legislation". https://www.parliament.nsw.gov.au/lc/proceduralpublications/DBAssets/wppbook/15%20NSW%20LC%20Prac%20Ch14%20(press).pdf

@matty: thanks for the clarification.

@phoog: By the way, both the Australian and Canadian governments subscribe to the theory that the GG (as rep. of the Monarchy) belongs to two branches of gov't: both executive and legislative!

@phoog: Also, in the UK, the King is still formally the "fountain of justice", i.e. supreme judiciary too, although apparently this role was not formally extended to GGs in "the colonies". OTOH "The separation of courts from the monarch in person can be dated back to the famous Case of Prohibitions in 1607."

@Lookingforloopholes the fount of justice is not the same thing as a fountain of justice.  When did the governor general have the power to enact regulations on his own?

The regulation doesn't require the person using Anzac in the name of a product to have "proof"; it requires the person to have "approval of the minister" and places the burden of proof of that fact on the accused.
The linked guidelines make it clear that any grant of approval by the minister is conditional: any baked goods sold under a name that includes the word Anzac must comply with the guidelines.  The approval goes only that far; it is not a general grant of permission to use Anzac in the name of any biscuit whatsoever.
Any minister doing the job reasonably well will note this fact explicitly in any document granting approval, but even without such an explicit mention, it's likely that the existence of the guidelines would be sufficient.

Yeah, this interpretation makes more sense. It could also mean that any  approval could be (implicitly!) revoked by the gov't any time, for any reasons though, surely e.g. by  updating the Guidelines.

I'm guessing that (in a sense) it's like those contracts where one side can unilaterally change [e.g. the IP licensing] terms any time they see fit. Since this 'Anzac' branding is essentially a kind of IP licensing (e.g. WIPO lists it in their database as such) it makes some sense. (Yeah, there's advice to avoid those, but in case of literal gov't monopoly like this, it's 'take it or leave it'. And the notion of consent probably doesn't apply.)

@Lookingforloopholes Government Approval is NOT a contract. Contract is between two individuals. Approval by the government is the state, in its utmost gratitude, allowing you to do something that people without approval may not. Such as driving a car after fulfilling the tests or selling cookies called Anzac as long as they follow the recipe.

@Trish: yeah, but the gov't in most countries can't revoke someone's driver license simply by posting new guidelines on a website. So this situation is a bit non-standard, IMHO, in terms of the "due" process at least.

@Lookingforloopholes They can however alter where, what and when you can drive with your license arbitrarily. Such as changing "Class2" to "B"+"BE", but they also can just as arbitrarily impose a limit of "You can't be older than 70 and drive", or "you can't drive further than 500 km from your home." That is all within the power of the legislator.

Obligations to the government are legal but not contractual
Unless your obligation arises from an actual contract with the government.
A government-imposed obligation, say, to pay tax or not use the word ‘Anzac’ without permission, is not based on any notion of contract law. There is no element of consent; for example, it is an imposition backed by the government’s legal right to use force (e.g., imprisonment, fines, etc.).
Departmental guidelines are not legally enforceable
In a general sense, the executive arm of government is responsible for administering the law.
If the law mandates that this must be done in a certain way, then it must be done that way. Conversely, if it prescribes certain ways, then they must not be used.
However, the vast majority of laws (statutory or common law) aren’t that prescriptive. The leave to the executive the exact details of how the law will be administered.
Now, the executive will develop policies, procedures, and guidelines for administering the law. They may even publish them. But, it is a settled part of the common law that they are not bound to follow them.
Of course, it’s also a settled part of common law that administrative decision-makers can’t act arbitrarily or capriciously. So, if they depart from their guidelines, they need to explain their reasons in their decision if they want to survive judicial review. However, if they depart from the law, their decision is void.
So, in relation to Anzac, the guidelines serve to inform the public (and the department) of the sorts of things that will likely be given permission and the sorts of things that likely won’t. However, each application is assessed on its individual merits.
What it means in practice
If you were to seek permission to make Anzac biscuits that did not use the traditional ingredients or allergen-free substitutes for them (i.e. not Anzac biscuits), the guidelines suggest that your application would be refused. However, if through incompetence or otherwise it were granted, then you would not be in breach of the law as you have the ministerial approval the law requires.
However, if this were brought to the government's attention, your approval would almost surely be revoked, and from that point on, continuing to market them would be an offence.
Alternatively, if your question is about what happens if you lie on your application: that is you ask for approval to do X, get approval for X and then do Y instead, you are committing an offence because you don't have approval to do Y.

"your approval would almost surely be revoked". The Regulations (in question) do not explicitly provide for this. I guess there might some 'common law' or 'common sense' provision that the government could invoke in a court. Do you have any example of this actually happening and being upheld in an Australian court, in the absence of an explicit provision in a law/Regulation that allows for withdrawal of approval, after it was given?

@Lookingforloopholes the approval is conditional.  It isn't necessary to revoke permission when someone sells nonconforming biscuits as "Anzac biscuits" because the person never had permission to sell them under that name.

@Lookingforloopholes: The "approval would be revoked" describes a hypothetical case where the government made a mistake and did not apply the Regulations. You can't reason about simultaneously applying and not-applying the Regulations. In that hypothetical case, first the Regulations are not applied, and then later they are applied.
